# Extending Field for End Template

Tags: angular-formly

I am looking for a way to extend the standard fields in angular-formly to have things like a help icon for some fields, or custom template after the field.

Is there a way to extend it the base field to have a custom template just for after each field without having to redefine every field template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! you can create a **wrapper** template with the helper markup and apply it to other types. Example:

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function config(formlyConfigProvider) {

  formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
    name: 'helper',
    templateUrl: '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></em> </button>'
  });

  formlyConfigProvider.setType({
    name: 'input',
    template: '<input class="form-control" ng-model="model[options.key]">',
    wrapper: ['helper', 'bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
  });

});
```

More info: http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/custom-templates#creating-a-custom-template

Bootstrap templates: https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap